# Delete an object from an array

Tags: swift

I have created two buttons (add and edit):

```
var addButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "tabBarAddClicked"); self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self.editButtonItem(), addButton]
```

These also work and I can delete objects from the `tableView` with the function

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        subjects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Hereby:

```
var subjects: [Subject] = subjectsData
```

and

```
var subjectsData = [ Subject(name: "Investments", semester: 1), Subject(name: "Statistics", semester: 1), Subject(name: "Studium Universale", semester: 2) ]
```

Though, when I go back in the navigation bar to the previous screen and then return to the screen, the deleted objects from the array are again there. But I told it to remove the objects from the array `subjectsData` with `subjects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)`.

Why do the objects return and how can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

> But I told it to remove the objects from the array subjectsData with
>   subjects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row).

You told it to remove from subjects, not subjectsData.

For example:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3]
var array2 = array1


array2.removeFirst()

print(array1) // [1, 2, 3]
print(array2) // [2, 3]
```

Comment: But is `subjects` not `subjectsData`because of `var subjects: [Subject] = subjectsData`?

Comment: If I change the code to `subjectsData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)`, the app crashes with the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'"